# MySQL+Debezium+Kafka topic( topic not created)

Tags: mysql, cdc, debezium

Using below properties

```
name=mysql
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=3306
database.user=root
database.password=admin
database.server.id=42
database.server.name=mysql
database.history.kafka.topic=dbhistory.sys
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
include.schema.changes=true
```

Loading like

```
bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat config\connect-standalone.properties config\mysql.properties
```

topics created

```
dbhistory.sys,mysql
```

but when any change in DB, no topic created.
I tried with mongo + debezium. Working fine. But not with MySQL.

Comment: are there any errors in the output from the Connect worker?

Comment: No..but the default topics that I mentioned dbhistory.sys and sys are created and empty. http://localhost:8083/connectors/mysql is also up

Comment: Are the connector and task in status RUNNING when checking via http://connect-host:8083/connectors/<your connector>/status? Are you perhaps applying any whitelist/blacklist configuration that includes no tables at all?

Comment: I got issue...It was going to sys schema of table. I created my own schema in mysql and is working fine.Thanks you all.

Comment: @Sri Can you elaborate? I am also facing same issue.. my connector status is running. but only topic in `database.history.kafka.topic` is created.

Comment: https://medium.com/groww-engineering/moving-from-hibernate-envers-to-debezium-bae4856c0e1b

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to whitelist the table to whom you have enable CDC and want Debezium to create topics for those tables by adding these properties in connector.properties file:

1. database.dbname=Which data base you want to point
2. table.whitelist=<schema.table1. schema.table2>